# RaspberryPi CM4 にて、Pythonを使用し、SPI通信で外部のEEPROMにアクセスしますが、値の読み書きができません。

Tags: python, python3, raspberry-pi

ラズパイからEEPROM(M95M04-DR)をSPIで接続しています。
Pythonを使用して、EEPROMの読み書きを行おうとしていますが、
メモリデータの取り出し以前に、レジスタの読み込み、設定も行えません。
初めての工作で理由がわからず苦戦しています。
構文誤り、考え方の誤り、修正方法等あれば教えてください。

```
import spidev
import time

READ = 0x03 # 0000 0011 read
RDSR = 0x05 # 0000 0101 read status register
WRSR = 0x01 # 0000 0001 write status register

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 10000000
spi.mode = 3

#write register
spi.xfer2([WREN]
time.sleep(0.1)
spi.xfer2([WRSR,0x0A])　#とりあえず何かを設定できるか確認

#read register
res = spi.xfer2([RDSR, RDSR])[1]
print("res:" + str(res)) 　# 1byte(SRWD/ 0 / 0 / 0 / BP1 / BP0 / WEL / WIP) を想定
time.sleep(0.1)

#read
data= spi.xfer2([READ, 0x00200, 0x00])
print("data" + str(data))
```

```
res:255  (たまに 253 となる。なぜ…？)  
data:[255,255,255] (たまに[255,255,127] となる。なぜ…？)
```

Answer (score 0):

SPI の通信について誤解があるようです。 `xfer2` の挙動と合わせて理解すると吉。

SPI は

- マイコンが `CS#=L` にする
- マイコンが `MOSI` からコマンドを出力する

  - この間もマイコンは `MISO` を読んでいるが、信号の状態が無意味なので結果を無視する義務がある
- チップが `MISO` に返事が返す

  - この間もマイコンは `MOSI` を出力しなければならない
  - チップ側はこの間の `MOSI` を無視する義務がある
- マイコンが `CS#=H` にして１物理トランザクションの終了

というハードウエアプロトコルです。んで `xfer2` はこの一連の処理を一括で行うものです。

`Read Status` 05h コマンドは上記のごとく

- `MOSI` に 05h を送る（がマイコンはこの間も `MISO` を読む義務がある）
- `MISO` に値が 8bit で帰ってくる（がこの間もマイコンは `MOSI` に出力する義務がある）

ので、都合１６ビットの転送を行い、マイコンとしては前半が 05h の送信、後半が status の受信となるわけです。

`xfer2()` は引数としてバイト値のリストを受け取り、結果としてバイト値のリストを返す仕様となっているので

```
result = spi.xfer2([5,何でもよいゴミ値])
```

とすることで

- 都合 16bit の転送が行われる
- `MOSI` の前半に 05h 後半に何でもよいゴミ値が出力される

  - チップ側は 05h を受け取った時点で `Read status` と解釈し、ゴミ値は無視する
- `MISO` の前半 8bit が `result[0]` に、後半 8bit が `result[1]` に得られる
- すでに書いた通り、マイコンソフトのほうは

  - `result[0]` は無視しなきゃならない
  - `result[1]` が `Read status` の返事のはず

という動作になります。

Answer (score 0):

お忙しい所、ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
xfer2の仕組みについて少し理解が深まりました。
お礼申し上げます。

頂いた内容を元に、ソースを少し変更してみましたが、
レジスタ設定値を取得した値は 255 のまま変わらずでした。
マスター側、スレーブ側、または双方で何か別の問題があるのかもしれません。
引き続き学習を進めたいと思います。。

```
#read register
res = spi.xfer2([RDSR, 0x00])
print("res:" + str(res[1]))
res:255
```

Comment: 質問者本人のようですが、質問時と異なるアカウントになっているようです。当サイトはスレッド式の掲示板では無いので、追加情報は回答ではなく質問に追記する必要があります。意図せずアカウントが分かれてしまった場合には、ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。 [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)