# ラズパイのPythonの数値（小数点）をArduinoにどうにか伝えたい(SPI or I2C)

Tags: python, c++, c, raspberry-pi, arduino

私は大学の研究のためにここ５日ほど，ラズパイのPythonの数値（小数点）をArduinoにどうにか伝えようと(SPI or I2C)色んなサイトを奔走しています．(そのため私の過去質問は似たような内容で埋め尽くされています．

あるいは以下のサイトでも
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/what-numbers-are-they-ieee-754-arduino-float/1033366/5

しかしながら結果は芳しくありません．（以下に試してきたことを書いておきます）
もちろん，あらゆるサイトを見てきましたが，まともな例が一つもありませんでした．（海外サイトを含めて）
そこで抽象的な質問になってしまい，申し訳ないのですが，「皆さんはラズパイが計算した値をarduinoに伝えたい，という場面に遭遇した時にどうしていますか？」
もし普段使っているコードがあればそのまま教えていただきたいですし，あるいはそれを実現しているサイトをご存知のようであれば教えていただきたいです．

これは何も，すべてを皆様に全投しているわけではなく，五日間という日を投資して足掻いた結果が芳しくなく，そもそもの考えの枠組みから見直すために質問させていただいているということです．

#### 試したこと

数を1byte単位で送り，Arduinoの中でIEEE754に変換する方法はうまくいきましたが，基点となる信号を送れないため（Arduinoにとっては全てが等しく数字のため），Arduino側でbyteをカウントする必要があるために，一度読み間違えたらドミノ倒しになります．(SPI, I2C)
これはstrに変換して送る方法でも言えます．(I2C)
結局スレーブにする時点で，「byteが来るたびに格納」する必要があり，そのbyteの受け取りミスを防ぐ方法が全てにおいて必要なのです．が，そのようなサイトを見つけることができませんでした．

過去質問はこちら
[ラズパイ to Arduino: SPI送受信のタイミングが合わずに乱れる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91206/41334)

usbシリアルはサイトを見かけましたが，肝心のマシン（arduinoに渡った数値はモーター指令速度になります）が動かず，デバグしようにもusbポートを物理的に塞いでいるので，この案は棄却されました

Comment: 英語にはなりますが、Stack Exchange には Aruduino 向けのサイトも用意されているので参考にしてください。 https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 以前の質問 [Python (ラズパイ）で計算した数値をC言語(Arduino)にfloatとして送信したいです](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91138/26370) に回答した内容が同様に適用出来ますよ。色々とやりたい事やった事が二転三転して忘れてしまったのでは？

Comment: 難しく考えすぎなんじゃないですか？以前の質問で文字列で送受信した方がいいいってアドバイスもありましたし、"Arduino 文字列 受信" で検索するだけでもすぐ情報が出てくるでしょう。

Comment: kunifさん
 ありがとうございます．しかし数を数字にしてそれ区切って送っても，今と同じように同期の問題にぶつかります．3.141592を文字列にして(str),python

Comment: kunifさん
 ありがとうございます．しかし数を数字にしてそれ区切って送っても，今と同じように同期の問題にぶつかります．3.141592を文字列にして(str),ラズパイから送る行為は本質的にはバイトで分けるのと違いがありません．そうして送られたデータというのは，確かし，while(Wire.avaiable()){ data[++i] = Wire.read()}のように読めます．しかしこれはArduinoがマスター側だからできるのであって，スレーブだと，例えばOnReceveで割り込みをかける，あるいはwire.readをmain loopで回すにしても，どちらにせよバイトをタイミング良く読める（一回もミスらない）ことにかかっています．なのでレシーブで読んでいる限り，SPIにしろI2Cにしろ同期が乱れるのを止める工夫が必要になります．それがどこにも載っていません

Comment: 可変長文字列で条件や時間が多岐にわたるのが嫌なら16進数文字列を使う方法で長さを固定にすれば良いでしょう。長さやフォーマットが合っているかを判定し、合っていれば有効なデータとして使用し、合わなければ無効なデータとして破棄する形ですね。無効なデータ発生が頻発するようなら通信速度を下げるとか送信側で適当なディレイを入れるとかの工夫をしてみましょう。例えばキチンと研究が進めばArduinoが1つ数値を受け取る毎に、それに対応したモーター制御を行う必要があるはずです。それにはある程度の時間がかかり、その間は次の数値を受信しても意味が無いのでは？ Raspberry Piが次の数値を送るにはその時間を待ってから行えば良いと思われます。

Comment: https://garretlab.web.fc2.com/arduino_reference/language/functions/communication/serial/readStringUntil.html これでいいのでは。floatの生バイトデータを送らず文字列にした方がいい理由としては、通信データの開始と終端の定義・判定が容易、文字列と数値は相互変換が難しくない、ほぼプラットフォーム依存を気にしなくてよいという点。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

そういうのは「電文」の設計ということになります。電文とは何らかの方法で最初と最後とチェックデジットがわかるもの、ということになりそうです。よくある RS232 で計測器→ PC に測定値を知らせるような場合

`[STX]` ASCII 文字だけ使った電文 `[ETX]` チェックデジット

のようにしておくと開始を知るには `[STX]=0x02` が見つかるまで読み捨てればよくて、そののち `[ETX]=0x03` があるまで受け取ればいいわけです。更にチェック方法に従ってチェックデジットを自分で計算し、自分の計算結果と受け取った値が異なっていれば破棄するなどを行います（ノイズが混入しうる距離の伝送が前提なので）

この手続きだと本文に `STX`/`ETX` と同じ値を含むことができないので情報密度が上げられません。それが許容される場合にしか使われません。

SPI の場合 `#CS=H→L` で電文開始 `#CS=L` が継続している間が電文本文 `#CS=L→H` で電文終了、外来ノイズから隔離されている同一基板内の通信しか想定していないのでチェックデジットは無し、ということで十分です。

I2C でも `[スタートコンディション]` 電文 `[ストップコンディション]` となり、同様チェックデジットはなし、が基本です。

なので SPI や I2C ではどこで電文が開始終了するかはほぼ自明であり、わざわざ解説記事に詳細を記載するまでもないのです（当たり前すぎて解説不要だから記事を見つけられていないだけ）

今回 SPI で伝送することを選ぶなら SPI バス上 32bit Transaction が可能なのに対して、今 Payload として 8bit しか載せていないようなので 24bit 分無駄な転送をしている可能性があります。 SPI の空き部分に `コマンド` あるいは `データ種別` として `データX の bit0-15` のように区別できる何かを載せるといいでしょう。

---

RaspberryPI の `spi.xfer2` はバイトの列を１つのトランザクションで送る仕様なので、１回の `spi.xfer` の呼び出しによって

- `#CS=H→L` にする
- 指定したバイト列をその順に送信する
- `#CS=L→H` にする

という挙動をします。伝送したいデータが１種類しかないならバイト列として本文だけ用意すれば十分で、複数種類あればそれを判別する別バイトを用意すればよいわけです。

- 前者なら `spi.xfer2([0x40,0x49,0x0F,0xD8])` (32bit Transaction)
- 後者なら `spi.xfer2([種類,0x40,0x49,0x0F,0xD8])` (40bit Transaction)

種類の値は送る側と受ける側で合意した任意の値

Arduino の受信側は全然知らないので SPI の受信ロジックが `#CS` を受け付けるのか否か、何ビットの伝送ができるのかを確かめてください。 `#CS` を受け付けるのであれば電文の開始終了は `#CS` で判断できるので小細工は不要。  40bit Transaction ができないのなら 32bit 以下 Transaction にしなきゃならないので、データを分割する必要が生じます。 16bit 値と電文の種類（何のどこ）も受け渡す、なんてことになります。

see also; [RaspberryPi CM4 にて、Pythonを使用し、SPI通信で外部のEEPROMにアクセスしますが、値の読み書きができません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90231/)

Comment: またもやありがとうございます．前回，成功した！と思っていたのですが連続で通信させると，Arduinoの読み間違いか頻発しました．おっしゃることは理解できます．つまりPyhon「ここから読んでね」というのを何か特別に送信する必要があるのですよね．ですがその途中で失敗してしまった場合はおかしなデータはどちらにせよ生成されるのではないでしょうか？例えば，Pythonのspi.xfer2で4バイトのリストを送りますが，これはどうやら逐一送信しているのと変わらないみたいで（割り込みが四回発生する），結局その初回のタイミングがあっても４回のうち１回でも失敗すればおじゃんになります

Comment: これを具体的にはどう解決すれば良いでしょうか?

Comment: ここでは長くなるかもしれませんので，ぜひこちらにお願いします　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91206/41334

Comment: >「今回 SPI で伝送することを選ぶなら SPI バス上 32bit Transaction が可能なのに対して、今 Payload として 8bit しか載せていないようなので 24bit 分無駄な転送をしている可能性があります。 SPI の空き部分に コマンド あるいは データ種別 として データX の bit0-15 のように区別できる何かを載せるといいでしょう。」　　　　なるほど，少しずつ少しずつ仰っている事がわかってきました．SPIは一回の伝送に単に8bitを渡しているだけではなく，コマンドやその他も含めた合計32bitの伝送をしている（だから前回のご回答では，下位8bitを抜き出す必要があった．)

Comment: そして今回の連続のループではそのような切り捨てていた処理の部分に何かの数字を差し込む（例えば，Arduinoには受信した32bitのうち上位8bitも常に目を光らせておいて，ある数字例えば255になった瞬間を4byte目の目印にするという事ですね

Comment: つまり，以前のdata[i]&0xFF
のbitアンド処理はつまりは下位8bit以外を0にして抜き出す行為であり，今回は別のとこに４回カウントのための隠し球を仕込んでおけばいいという事ですね．例えばArduinoに受信された32bitのうち，上位8bitに隠し球を仕掛けられる方法がPython側にあるのなら，4byte目伝送データの上位8bitを255, とでもしておいて，Arduinoには伝送データを下位8bitを保持+上位8bitが255か否かを確認して4回の伝送の完了を感じ取らせる，という感じですね

Comment: では実装するために解決しなければならないのは，「その隠し球をどこの何bitに仕込むか．あるいは仕込む事が可能なのか」「そしてそれを設定するのはPython側で可能か，可能ならばどのようなメソッドか」ということになってきますね．あ，いやそういうのは全て込みで spi.xfer2に搭載されているのですかね

Comment: 今，実験してわかったのですが，SPIからは8bitデータしか伝わっていないようです．つまり，コマンドとかも何もなしで，
    for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) { f.bytes[i]=(uint8_t)(data[i]); }として使えます．おそらく  data[count]=SPDR;　としている時点で，ペイロードのみを抽出という操作になっています

Comment: > 「SPI の場合 #CS=H→L で電文開始 #CS=L が継続している間が電文本文 #CS=L→H で電文終了、外来ノイズから隔離されている同一基板内の通信しか想定していないのでチェックデジットは無し、ということで十分です」　この文章を見落としていました．なるほど，これが起電するかいなかを合図にしているのですね．となるとArduino側は，CSピンをdigitalReadで受けているわけですね

Comment: ですが，GPIOは3.3Vなので，5VをHIGHと捉えるArduinoにとっては，感知しにくい合図じゃないですか？あ！もしかしてそれでタイミングが乱れているのかもしれません

Comment: えっと、ストーリー的にソフトウエアの話をしていますが、これらはすべてハードウエア的な接続の完全性は保証されている前提です。 5V 電源でも 3.3V を H として受け取る仕様の CMOS IC もあります。そうでないのもあります。 Arduino が 3.3V を H と受け取らないのならレベルシフタが必要なのできっちり入れてください。ソフトの話はそのあと。

Comment: ありがとうございます．この記事によると，一応Arduinoは3.0VからちゃんとHIGHと扱うはずですが，https://forum.arduino.cc/t/will-an-arduino-recognize-a-3-3-input-as-high/853015/2 , ラズパイが必ずしも3.0~3.3を立ち上がりで出しているのかというところが不確かですね．例えば，pi一回の送信では成功するのに，while Trueの連続送信では乱れるのは，ラズパイ側がその連続送信の何度かは3.0V以上の立ち上げに失敗しているからかもしれません．（結果としてタイミングがずれる．）ちゃんとレベルシフタ入れてみます（Masterがラズパイの限り，3.3Vの送信でスレイブは破損しないので直接ピンを繋いでいました）

Answer (score 2):

区切りを電文内でつけなければならない場合、

- 文字列で送る

非常に単純です。`123.4`という数値を送りたいなら`"123.4"`という文字列を送ります。
メッセージの区切りは制御文字を使います。大抵改行です。
複数の種類の値を扱う場合はコマンド文字列を先頭に付け加えたりします。
マイコン側で文字列をパースする必要があるのが難点ですが、
Arduinoなら特に問題にはならないでしょう。
特に理由がなければ文字列で送ります。

- バイナリで送る

文字列で送ると通信速度の問題がある場合は仕方なくこちらを選びます。
メッセージの区切りを認識するために送るデータのチェックサムなどを含めたヘッダーを作り、
マイコン側で区切れを探索します。

---

上は電文の中で電文の区切りを持たせる場合ですが、今回の場合そもそもSPIですので
CS信号を区切りに使うことができます。

Raspi側はCSを下げたままにしてデータ、例えば"123.4"を送信し(xfer2でまとめて送るとそうなる、または明示的にCSを操作する)
Arduino側ではCSを監視してL->Hになった時点でデータ転送が終了したと判断します。

Comment: ありがとうございます，はい，その発想は理解しています．

Comment: しかし，いざ実装する時には，Pythonが送る"123.4"はナンバイトかに分割されるので，それをスレーブはうまいこと受け取らねばなりません．スレーブが受け取る手段はonreceiveの割り込みか，attatchinterrupt, あるいはmain loopで回すことです

Comment: そのどちらにせよ，Arduinoはバイトに分かれたものを順番正しく保持し，揃ったら結合，をしなければなりません

Comment: これの方法がどこにも載っておらず困っています．どのサイトもArduinoがます他，あるいはスレーブだけど１byte受け取るだけ，で参考になりません

Comment: Arduino側ではuint8_tの受信バッファを持ちます、データを受信するたびバッファの末尾にデータを書きます、区切り文字(例えば改行)が来たらそれ以前に受信したデータを数値文字列とみなしてパースします。パースしたらバッファをクリアします(次に受信したときに書き込むインデックスを0に戻す)

Comment: もしかしたらデータが飛んだり化けたりすることを気にしているかもしれませんが、spi の時点でほぼないです

Comment: ありがとうございます．なるほど，ではArduinoの処理の文章の問題なのですね

Comment: というかspiならCS信号を利用して区切りを認識できそうです

Comment: はい！今取り組んでみています，ありがとうございます

Answer (score 2):

> そのどちらにせよ，Arduinoはバイトに分かれたものを順番正しく保持し，揃ったら結合，
> をしなければなりません。
> これの方法がどこにも載っておらず困っています．どのサイトもArduinoがます他，
> あるいはスレーブだけど１byte受け取るだけ，で参考になりません。

これはRS232C等でも同様ですが、一般的にデータの頭にSTX、データの最後にETX等をつけ、
さらにデータの整合性をチェックするために、STXの後に送るデータ数をつけ、ETXの前にCRCコードをつけることにより、受信して結合したデータに欠落がないかチェックします。
データが1つ欠落していた場合、STXの後のデータ数と実際のデータ数が異なりますし、CRCの値も違ってきます。
当然ですが、データ自身はは文字に変換して送ります。

別の方法としては、1バイトデータのうち、下の4ビットのみをデータ用とし、
上位の4ビットはなんバイト目、これで終わり等意味で使用する方法があると思います。